# File not found Issue on Selenium robot

Tags: java, selenium

When I upload files through selenium, a few files are not found on my pc.
How to handle this issue? Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
StringSelection ss1 = new StringSelection(filename+".pdf");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss1, null);
Thread.sleep(2000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
Thread.sleep(4000);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
thread.sleep(4000);

//submit
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*['Option']")).click();
```

Comment: Usually if a computer says "file not found" it's telling the truth. Often that happens because you use a relative file path and the code isn't looking where you assume it's looking.

Comment: You used the tag "robotframework" which refers to a python-based acceptance testing framework. Your code doesn't look anything like that. Are you actually asking about robotframework (robotframework.org), or some other framework with "robot" in the name?

Comment: thank u,I'm using: Robot Class in Selenium Webdriver